# ATBS with Python - Error with Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python, string, list, typeerror

Hello this is my first time posting so I hope I add all the detail needed. I am currently in Chapter 4 of Automate The Boring Stuff With Python by Al Sweigart.

On the project for Conway's Game of life I run into an error after I get 20 lines of output. I get 1 of 2 errors that produce from lines 63 and 66.

```
# Conway's Game of Life
import random, time, copy
WIDTH = 60
HEIGHT = 20

# Create a list of list for the cells
next_cells = []
for x in range(WIDTH):
    column = [] # Create a new column
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            column.append('#') # Add a living cell
        else:
            column.append(' ') # Add a dead cell
    next_cells.append(column) # next_cells is a list of column lists

# Start of main loop
while True:
    print('\n\n\n\n\n') # Separate each step with newlines
    current_cells = copy.deepcopy(next_cells)

    # Print current_cells on the screen
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        for x in range(WIDTH):
            print(current_cells[x][y], end='') # Print the # or space
        print() # Print a newline at the end of the row

        # Calculate the next step's cells based on current step's cells
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            # Get neighboring coordinates
            # '% WIDTH' ensures left_coord is always between 0 and WIDTH - 1
            left_coord = (x - 1) % WIDTH
            right_coord = (x + 1) % WIDTH
            above_coord = (y - 1) % HEIGHT
            below_coord = (y + 1) % HEIGHT

            # Count number of living neighbors
            num_neighbors = 0
            if current_cells[left_coord][above_coord] == '#':
                num_neighbors += 1 # Top left neighbor is alive
            if current_cells[x][above_coord] == '#':
                num_neighbors += 1 # Top neighbor is alive
            if current_cells[right_coord][above_coord] == '#':
                num_neighbors += 1 # Top right neighbor is alive
            if current_cells[left_coord][y] == '#':
                num_neighbors += 1 # Left neighbor is alive
            if current_cells[right_coord][y] == '#':
                num_neighbors += 1 # Right neighbor is alive
            if current_cells[left_coord][below_coord] == '#':
                num_neighbors += 1 # Bottom left neighbor is alive
            if current_cells[x][below_coord] == '#':
                num_neighbors += 1 # Bottom neighbor is alive
            if current_cells[right_coord][below_coord] == '#':
                num_neighbors += 1 # Bottom right neighbor is alive

            # Set cell based on Conway's Game of Life rules
            if current_cells[x][y] == '#' and (num_neighbors == 2 or num_neighbors == 3):
                # Living cells with 2 or 3 neighbors stay alive
                next_cells = '#'
            elif current_cells[x][y] == ' ' and num_neighbors == 3:
                # Dead cells with 3 nighbors become alive
                next_cells[x][y] = '#'
            else:
                # Everything else dies or stays dead
                next_cells[x][y] = ' '
    time.sleep(1) # Add a 1-second pause to reduce flickering
```

Line 63 produces - next_cells[x][y] = '#'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Line 66 produces - next_cells[x][y] = ' '
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

The weird thing is, next_cells is defined as a list on line 7. And I printed it at the end of the loop each time to make sure it was staying as a list. I also checked for indentation issues which I did correct but still get an error later in the program as previously described. I also have looked up other questions similar to this but nothing was close enough to my issue from what I could tell.

I am not new to programming but I still lack a lot of knowledge so any type of help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's because you define `next_cells` as a string on line 60

Comment: That was it! Wow, goes to show how easy it is to miss things like that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 60, you assign `next_cells = '#'` which converts next_cells into a str.
later you try to assign `next_cells[x][y] = '#'` at which point next_cells is not a list but a str.

Whenever the first if statment triggers, it converts the `next_cells` list into a `str` object and will result in an error the next time it runs any of the other elif statements.

Comment: You are right! Henry mentioned that as well. You guys are quick thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running `mypy` (a static type checker that you can read about at http://mypy-lang.org/) over this code on a hunch that it'd reveal the problem, and sure enough:

```
gol.py:60: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "List[List[str]]")
```

which is exactly right; it's telling you that you've defined `next_cells` as a list of lists, and you're overwriting it with a string:

```
                next_cells = '#'
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you for the reference as well I will read about mypy.